# Keeping values from an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing a code that will go over each word in words, look them up in dictionary and then append the dictionary value to counter. However if I print counter, I only get the last number from my if statement, if any. If I place print counter inside the loop, then I get all the numbers for each individual word, but no total value.
My code is the following:

```
dictionary = {word:2, other:5, string:10}
words = "this is a string of words you see and other things"
if word in dictionary.keys():
   number = dictionary[word]
   counter += number
   print counter
```

my example will give me:

```
[10]
[5]
```

while I want `15`, preferable outside the loop, as in the real life code, words is not a single string but many strings which are being looped over.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `if word in dictionary:` suffices and is faster; `dictionary.keys()` first has to create a list object, after which the `in` operator has to scan that list. `word in dictionary` only has to calculate the hash to see if the key is present, a O(1) constant time operation.

Comment: *my example will give me* No, it won't. `counter += number` will give you a `NameError` or `UnboundLocalError` because `counter` is not defined elsewhere.

Comment: Nor will it print `[..]` as that implies you are printing one-element lists instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pretty straightforward example, that prints `15`:

```
dictionary = {'word': 2, 'other': 5, 'string': 10}
words = "this is a string of words you see and other things"

counter = 0
for word in words.split():
    if word in dictionary:
        counter += dictionary[word]
print counter
```

Note that you should declare `counter=0` before the loop and use `word in dictionary` instead of `word in dictionary.keys()`.

You can also write the same thing in one-line using `sum()`:

```
print sum(dictionary[word] for word in words.split() if word in dictionary)
```

or:

```
print sum(dictionary.get(word, 0) for word in words.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

you should declare the counter outside the loop. Everything else you do in your code is correct.
The correct code:

```
dictionary = {word:2, other:5, string:10}
words = "this is a string of words you see and other things"
counter = 0
if word in dictionary.keys():
   number = dictionary[word]
   counter += number

print counter
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing with that code, since I don't see any loop there. However, a way to do what you want would be the following:

```
sum(dictionary[word] for word in words.split() if word in dictionary)
```